# c# Word-AddIn convert activeDocument to a virtual PDF and merge them into one PDF document

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word, word-addins, document-conversion

I am creating multiple virtual documents and then I want to merge them into one PDF, without saving them somewhere. All I found for now are guides, in which they save the document as a PDF somewhere and then they read the PDF to merge them into one.

It should also be possible to combine multiple PDFs and not only two.

Comment: If the documents are not being saved, why create multiple document? Why not create everything as a single document then save that to PDF?

Comment: Because the document variable values are being changed. I want to save each document with the variable values and then change the variable value and save it again.

Comprende?

Comment: Nein, ich verstehe nicht ganz. No, I'm not following, exactly. I don't see how the documents can't be combined into one before creating the PDF.

Comment: Then show me how to combine multiple virtual documents into one.

Comment: On the one hand you use the term "virtual", on the other (in your comment) you say "I want to save each document with the variable values". It's not clear exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to save them somewhere? You could create temporary files at a place like `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp\%yourProject%`, work with those files, following the guide you've found and clean up afterwards. At least I don't see a problem with using temporary files and folders at the right place.

Comment: If my program has to save these documents as a PDF file in the temp director, it will take some time, to process that.
That's why I'm trying to avoid saving unnecessary files.